# Strange graphics artefacts in Android app

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, samsung-galaxy

I'm intermittently observing strange graphics artefacts in my app, as shown below. This is a screengrab from a Samsung Galaxy S3. I have only observed it on this particular phone. I have run the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 and an HTC One, and never observed this issue on either - although admittedly I do mainly use the S3 for development.

I considered that the issue might be some sort of concurrency clash in drawing to the Canvas (I'm using the basic Android rendering methods, no OpenGL or anything), since I can clearly recognise the repeating units of other UI elements, so I synchronized all the code which draws to or interacts with the Canvas and I'm *still* observing it happen.

It does clear itself up after around 30-90 seconds, which may be due to a regular scheduled memory cleanup operation it performs - so perhaps this is a manifestation of low available mem?

If I had enough rep I would stick a pretty big bounty on this. Any help appreciated. Hopefully someone recognises this particular problem.

[image: Strange graphics artefacts]

Comment: Have you tried to perform drawing with hardware layer on [`View#setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will give this a go. It may take a while to prove that the graphics errors no longer happen, but if it fixes things I will make sure to award the bounty to you.

Comment: Will post as an answer.

Comment: I will increase the bounty on this when it expires later today.

Answer (score 2):

Apply hardware layers:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Comment: Hi Aziz, I'm still getting the occasional graphics issues with your suggested fix - although I think it has made the display look a bit nicer, so I'll still vote up your answer at least. Thanks.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty, since I only just realised that it would have vanished into the ether if I didn't, but I'm still in search of an answer.